# Action script for date

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am an freelance animator in flash with very limited knowledge in AS3. I make animation videos in swf format and sell it for money. Most of the time, my clients give me a small script and ask for a sample based on the script without any watermark or logo embeded. I have to oblige in order to win the chance of getting the work. Most of the time, the client does not respond after they get the sample and I think that they are getting their work done for free.

I want to embed a script in AS3 in such a way that the video will play for only a pre-defined number of days( eg 3 days ) or till a particular date.

Please help

Comment: But why you don't just do the demo on line and If the client is satisfied, give him the real animation ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your animation in one MovieClip.
I named it **'animation'**, then set your expire date, I commented where to set

```
function getDaysBetweenDates(date1:Date, date2:Date) : int { 
    var oneDay:Number = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var date1Milliseconds:Number = date1.getTime();
    var date2Milliseconds:Number = date2.getTime();         
    var differenceMilliseconds:Number = date1Milliseconds - date2Milliseconds;
    return Math.round(differenceMilliseconds/oneDay);   
}

var year  : int = 2014;  //here you put the year, month and the day when you want to expire
var month : int = 12;
var day   : int = 28;

var daysRemaining = getDaysBetweenDates(new Date(year, month-1, day+1), new Date());
timeTXT.text = daysRemaining.toString(); //you can create dinamyc text and show to your client how much time he has befor the animation expire

if(daysRemaining <= 0) {
    animation.visible = false;  //here we make animation movieclip invisible if is expired
}
```

try it!

Hope this help!